# How to open outlook client on machine from browser to add calendar event?

Tags: javascript, outlook

I am trying to open outlook client from a website (i.e. from browser)

I can find a way to open outlook client if I want to mail someone like so:

```
<a href="mailto:name@gmail.com">Click here to mail</a>
```

Currently, I download .ics file on client machine and user can manually add an event to their default mail client by clicking on .ics file.

is there a way to directly open outlook client and add calendar event without having user to click on the .ics file?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You cannot execute shell commands on the client-side, like executing an application. That is a security hole and browsers will never let that happen.

Comment: oh i see, so the only option is to download .ics file to client. is that correct ? (another solution is to make those urls that redirects to online calendars)

Comment: Yes that will be the only option. So if I put my that comment as answer, will you accept it as answer?

Comment: Sure I think that is acceptable for me

Comment: Thanks and hope you will find a good solution.

Comment: Could you help me with this  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905144/mandrill-attachment-calendar-event-file-is-empty-in-attachment-with-node-js

Comment: Sure, let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute shell commands on the client-side, like executing an application. That is a security hole and browsers will never let that happen.